# Eliminar fila PHP JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php, html

quiero eliminar filas al pulsar el botón, pero no funciona, no realiza ninguna acción al pulsar el botón, no encuentro el error en JavaScript. Esta es la única parte que no funciona, el PHP, el envío de AJAX en otros scripts funciona perfectamente.

Gracias por la ayuda.

```js
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
                    <script>
                        
                       function eliminar(idpedido) {
         alert('entra');
        //ejecutas el ajax
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'eliminarpedido.php', //El la URL tienes un espacio
            data: {idpedido},
            success: function (data) { 
                location.reload();
            }
        })
    }
          </script>
```

```html
<table borde='2'>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Idpedido</th>
    <th>Pedido</th>
    <th>Estado</th>
    <th>Idempleado</th>
    <th>Idcocinero</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    // Bucle while que recorre cada registro y muestra cada campo en la tabla.
    while ($columna = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado ))  
    { ?>
         <tr name=pedidos id="<?php echo $columna ['idpedido']; ?>">
           <td><?php echo $columna ['idpedido']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $columna ['pedido']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $columna ['estado']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $columna ['idempleado']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $columna ['idcocinero']; ?></td>
           <td><button name="eliminar" type="button" class="btn btn-primary p-3 px-xl-4 py-xl-3" onclick="eliminar();" value="<?php echo $columna ['idpedido']; ?>"><span></span> Eliminar Pedido</button></td>
    <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Quieŕes eliminar la fila en el HTML, en la tabla de la base de datos o en ambas partes?

Comment: puedes explicar el codigo, que agregaste??? no veo de donde sale  $resultado o que relevancia tiene el codigo html embebido con php o si es alreves...

Comment: Quiero enviar el id mediante AJAX para eliminar esa fila en la BDD y después actualizo la página.

Comment: $resultado viene de la consulta pero es irrelevante, se carga la información de la consulta en la tabla y cada fila cuenta con un botón donde el value es el identificador de cada pedido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luego de un par de cosas corregidas, un par de líneas eliminadas y un par de cosas agregadas...

- En el evento `onclick` del botón, puedes pasarle como parámetro el oid del pedido y en `js` recibes dicho oid en la función `eliminar`
- El `value` y el `name` del botón son innecesarios para este caso
- Estabas cerrando el `tr` fuera del ciclo `while`
- En la url del `ajax` tienes un espacio en el nombre del archivo `php` *no deberías usar espacios en blanco en el nombramiento de archivos*

```
    <table borde='2'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Idpedido</th>
                <th>Pedido</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
                <th>Idempleado</th>
                <th>Idcocinero</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            // Bucle while que recorre cada registro y muestra cada campo en la tabla.
            while ($columna = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado ))  
            { ?>
                <tr>
                   <td><?php echo $columna['idpedido']; ?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $columna['pedido']; ?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $columna['estado']; ?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $columna['idempleado']; ?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $columna['idcocinero']; ?></td>
                   <td>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary p-3 px-xl-4 py-xl-3" onclick="eliminar('<?php echo $columna['idpedido'] ?>')">
                        Eliminar Pedido
                      </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        //recibes el idpedido como parámetro
        function eliminar(idpedido) {
            //ejecutas el ajax
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'eliminarpedido.php',
                data: {idpedido},
                success: function (data) { 
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Lo demás creo que está bien.

Prueba y comenta.

Comment: El problema es que por algún motivo no funciona JavaScript, al hacer click en el botón no pasa nada, no llama a la función. Pero gracias por las modificaciones. Voy a modificar el post para que veáis todo el código

Comment: Tienes las funciones dentro del mismo archivo o es un archivo independiente? Para verificar si la función se ejecuta, puedes usar alert dentro de la función `function eliminar(idpedido) { alert('entra'); ...`

Comment: No entra y no entiendo porque, lo cargo como en el resto de páginas y funciona sin problemas, no hay error de llaves...

Comment: Hay un error en la función eliminar, si lo encuentras. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Modifiqué la respuesta... En el `data` solo es necesario pasarle la variable o encerrar en comillas simples el `data: {'idpedido': idpedido},`. La consola mostraba claramente el error y no lo tuve en cuenta al modificar el código inicialmente. Una disculpa por ello.

Comment: Ese era un error pero continua sin funcionar no salta el alert que esta al entrar a la función

Comment: function eliminar(idpedido) {
             alert('entra');
            //ejecutas el ajax
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'eliminarpedido.php', //El la URL tienes un espacio
                data: {idpedido},
                success: function (data) { 
                    location.reload();
                }
            })
        }

Comment: Ingresa a esta sala de chat y continuemos la discusión en ella https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128328/eliminar-fila

Comment: Hola, te pregunte en la sala, ¿Cómo podría enviar dos variables en el mismo button? El código esta en la sala, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Aunque esa sería otra pregunta, te voy a ayudar... Serían dos parámetros, por lo tanto debes separar las fuentes en el evento `onclick` del `button`. Algo así: `onclick="linea('<?= $columna2['idpedido']  ?>','<?= $columna2['idproducto'] ?>')"`

Comment: Funciona, muchas gracias.